# object floats after collision with another object

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

So I have a cube with with a rigidbody (with kinematic turned off) and a plane under it without a rigidbody. I have a script on my Cube so that it can move up and down and when I try to collide my cube with the plane , my cube just starts to float and rotating. I added a short [clip](https://youtu.be/C2ShhYUqvBU) so you can see the problem. I just want my cube to stay on the plane and not float away. can anyone help me?

I added/deleted the rigidbody ,turned kinematic on/off and used different collisions detections on both objects. I tried different combinations but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

On the rigidbody component, try toggling on 'Use Gravity'. That should stop it floating away.  Is that desired behaviour you want?